# PL/SQL:"character string buffer too small" error for specific environment

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

Can't got the problem,that reproduced on my environment.

Result of running PL/SQL procedure on **my PC** on `Eclipse SQL Explorer`:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

If this procedure compiled on **other PC** on `Eclipse SQL Explorer` also,that all is OK.

**note:** If you ask,why `Eclipse SQl Explorer` - its' historical issue,because procedure isn't compiled under Oracle Sql Developer.

What is problem in my environment?

Thank you.

Comment: is the input data the same in both cases? This error normally means your code is attempting to assign a string to a variable that is too small for it..

Comment: @StevieG  absolutely identical procedures and their input params for run. The only difference,that if proc. compiled from other PC,that there is no such error.Perhaps,some SQL Explorer settings?

Comment: Are you getting the error when compiling, or running the proc? Would be useful if you could post the code..

Comment: getting error when running only,compilation is OK,procedure size is more than 1K lines

Comment: I'm stumped, then.. The procedure is running on the database, so it shouldn't matter what your SQL explorer settings are. Is the database hosted locally on your machines?

Comment: does this procedure use dynamic sql?  Do you have an execute immediate statement that is interpreted at runtime? (execute immediate some_string_statement using some_variable;)

Comment: @tbone  no,there is no execute immediate statement.This procedure use sql,aggregated from parts,is it dynamic?

Comment: @sergionni: Do you know which line has the error?  If you're handling exceptions use `dbms_utility.format_error_stack||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace` instead of `sqlerrm`, so you can see the line numbers.

Comment: I know the line number ,it refers to variable. It's variable length is is OK,if run on other environment

Comment: Are there CLOBs involved? I've seen odd issues crop up when working with large CLOBs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look for a significant difference in the client environments.  For instance, do they have different settings for NLS_LANG?  This could matter if you're using a multi-byte character or Unicode character set in your database.

Comment: thank you, for now I'm out of this task,anyway keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

Does your code use the DBMS_OUTPUT package?
Maybe you have a small [limit on DBMS_OUTPUT](http://www.oradev.com/dbms_output.jsp). Try and increase the size to the maximum allowed (32767).

Answer (score 1):

There's an optimization level for PL/SQL procedures. Could be one of your environments is compiling in 'normal' mode and the other in 'debug' mode.

Check the settings for that object in ALL_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS